# Is there a limit to Istio maximum number of Gateway resources?

Tags: kubernetes, dns, multi-tenant, istio-gateway

Using stackoverflow in my work for a long time ago, but actually asking my first question here :)

We currently have a K8s cluster with an Istio Ingress Gateway & cert-manager for our public facing TLS-terminated endpoint, and are willing to setup another public endpoint serving customers' own domain names (from their own dns provider).

Customers could go on their project back-office and ask to connect their project to their own domain name by filling a simple form & pasting the appropriate CNAME/A rule within their DNS provider.
These custom domain names would be served by another Ingress Gateway instance configured with 1 LetsEncrypt certificate per domain, generated from cert-manager using HTTP challenges.

However, I wonder about the relevance & scalability of this stack.
First, and as mentioned by this thread title, is there any limit to the number of Gateway resource that a single ingress gateway instance can handle ? We could group all custom rules into a single Gateway resource, but having a separate Gateway per customer would be far easier for maintenance / update / clean up processes. Theoretically this could go up to a few dozens or even 100+ Gateway resources.

As a side note, have you any specific feedback/recommendation on dynamically generating customers' own certificates &  ingress rules using this or other better approach ?
One consequence that I really dislike is that we have to push K8s manifests from one of our microservices (and grants persmissions to do so), using infrastructure code within application codebase and opening potential security flaws ...

Thanks !